# reg ex expression, just need to split on comma

Tags: java, regex, groovy

Test code here.  I want to augment my current regex to split on commas

```
String test = "This Is ,A Test"
println(test)
String noSpace = test.replaceAll("\\s","")
println(noSpace)
String[] words = noSpace.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9'-.]+")

words.each {
   println(it)
}
```

This produces the output

```
This Is ,A Test
ThisIs,ATest
ThisIs,ATest
```

Where I want it to produce the output

```
This Is ,A Test
ThisIs,ATest
ThisIs
ATest
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: `'-.` looks very fishy. It looks like `,` is included in the range.

Comment: If you have a problem and try to solve it with a regex, then you have two problems. `split()` method is really great for that or you could use a `StringTokenizer` which is not actually encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cite from javadoc

> Note that a different set of metacharacters are in effect inside a character class than outside a character class. For instance, the regular expression . loses its special meaning inside a character class, while the expression - becomes a range forming metacharacter.

So you need to escape the dash:

```
String[] words = noSpace.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9'\\-.]+");
```

Answer (score 2):

To split based on comma, simply use

```
String[] words = noSpace.split(",");
```

Comment: I want to augment my current regex expression

Comment: @Badmiral: if all you want to do is split on a comma, then use the right tool for the job (`split()`).  If you have other requirements, then update your question to state those requirements.  The correct answer to your question as currently stated is to use `split`.  Do not be seduced into using something sexy (regexes) when something simpler works well.